# Is subjectivity a deeply integral part of human intelligence? Why?

Tags: values, intelligence

I believe that at its core, intelligence requires that some form of “good” or “bad” value judgments be made during the perception process. Values are the motivation behind an objective or goal. Values are the answer to the question, “Why?

Must intelligence continue to evolve based on values, or is it philosophically possible to have a form of intelligence that is not based on values?

Comment: Most humans certainly do **not** act (of course here excluding physiological responses) based on any system whatsoever, not to say a value-based system. Instead, most humans act mostly based on habit (including habitual thought patterns), and most habits are due to societal influence. For example see: 1. [The gender biases that shape our brains](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20210524-the-gender-biases-that-shape-our-brains) (https://archive.is/E2cqR) 1. [Stereotype that girls aren’t interested in STEM subjects ingrained in kids as young as 6](https://studyfinds.org/stereotype-girls-not-in

Comment: I think what is lacking in this question isn't just what you mean by values", but what you mean by "intelligence". Because many would define intelligence along the lines of "the capability to process information and makes decisions to achieve an objective." Since it sounds like you are just using "values" as a synonym for "objective" I can only assume you have some other definition of intelligence which as gone unshared. But there is one potential alternate definition that would yield an answer of a non-value based intelligence. If your definition of intelligence is merely the capability "the

Comment: The comments prompted by your question should make it amply clear to you that your use of the words 'values' is far too ambiguous. The ambiguity is compounded by the addition of the words 'based on'. It seems to me that any activity performed by the human mind can be said to be 'based on values' if those words are free to be interpreted to the greatest extent. If I put on clothes before I go out because a) it is cold and b) I don't want to get arrest for indecency, you could say I am being directed by values. If I study three years for a PhD you can say my intellectual effort is driven by valu

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152221/discussion-on-question-by-netcentric-intelligence-based-on-something-other-than); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I have tried to heavily revise your question to focus on a core component of it.

Comment: @JuliusHamilton To my mind you have changed my original question to such a degree that it has become your question, not mine, and so I will no longer be participating in this thread. You can close it, however you do that, if you wish.

Comment: From the pov of a utilitarianist or consequentialist as your Captain Obvious, the real trick perhaps lies at realizing on the journey to achieve your value goal there're various kinds of hard and soft *constraints*, thus usually it's not direct or straightforward yet quite confusing, challenging and simultaneously interesting, in some cases it may be even appear contradicting but actually aligning...

Answer (score 3):

Humans, like other animals, work for Dopamine, a “pleasure hormone”. Any activity, good or bad, that can produce Dopamine in our brain creates value for us. Intelligence can either help or hinder this process.

Comment: Well thats true; and Ive upvoted. But its simplistic. You need to add serotonin at the least to the cocktail. Also [endorphins oxytocin](https://www.parkinsonsnsw.org.au/four-happy-hormones/) testosterone prolactin estrogen... [See also](http://blog.languager.org/2010/05/declaration-imperation-and-language.html)

Comment: Too simplistic. Even if you grant that humans work only for pleasure (which is debatable itself), dopamine isn't "the pleasure hormone." Pleasure is a complex interaction of multiple chemicals and patterns of neural activity, dopamine only being a part of this process.

Comment: @causative - there is a more important question. Who controls endorphins? Our built-in instincts (like the reproduction process) or God (when writing research article).

Answer (score 1):

## Intelligence == Values

Intelligence is ultimately about control. If an agent can perceive but cannot act, then I question whether it has intelligence. It certainly does not have *observable* intelligence. Even the ability to speak is an *action*. So if you can't query it, and it just sits there like a rock, then there is no useful way in which to ascribe intelligence to it. As soon as it *can* act, we can say that intelligence determines the *optimality of action*. This is the difference between an LLM and a book. They both contain significant quantities of recognizable information, but only one of them can *act*.

The problem is that "optimum" is not an absolute concept. It is always relative to some metric. While we can make philosophical arguments about why some metrics are better than others, it should go without saying that there is no universally agreed ordering of all metrics (though religious people will obviously disagree).

Therefore, intelligence may only be measured against a chosen set of metrics. And a different agent, optimizing a different set of metrics, may decide that some agent regarded as "intelligent" is actually "stupid", and we see this happening amongst humans almost every day. In many cases, the label "stupid" really just means: "I disagree with that action" and has no greater justification.

A "metric", as I am using it, is literally just a *scale of values* assigned to actions or outcomes. So trying to suggest that there might be an "intelligence" that somehow "transcends" values is quite a bit like suggesting the existence of a being made of "pure energy". It is nonsense at every level. Every being that we regard as "intelligent" measures the effectiveness of actions, its own and others, because that is an absolute requirement for even determining how to choose one action over another. A being which does not make a distinction is not "intelligent"...it is *random*. You'd have a hard time convincing me that a "stochastic being" somehow "transcends intelligence".

## Phase Space

Another way to look at it is in terms of phase space. The universe is a collection of particles and energy densities (which are the same thing, if you want to get technical). When it "evolves", it is just moving from one configuration to another. Or, you could say that it is moving from one point in its phase space to another, and that the way the points are connected define the laws of physics.

Now, "life" is a particular *local* configuration  which tries to cause the universe to evolve into future states in which essential details of that local configuration are preserved (like, the creature has all its bits on the inside). So a simple way to say this is that a subset of possible states is *preferred* over other states. A local configuration which *conspires* to make the preferred states more probable could be said to have *agency* and be expressing a *preference* for the desired states. In this way, life itself could be considered the lowest level of intelligence, as it acts to keep its corner of the universe in a preferred subset of states (where its constituent bits are highly localized, rather than spread out over a large area).

Intelligence, then, can be seen merely as an elaboration of the homeostatic-seeking tendencies of life in general. It is an emergent phenomenon which helps maintain the homeostatic goal of low-level life at a very high level of abstraction. After all, the individual cells in your body have no idea that there is a fire 3 miles away, so you shouldn't walk there. A collection of billions of them, however, *do* know this fact and can use it to steer the cellular juggernaut in a safer direction. Thus, intelligence can be regarded as "super-life".

Every entity that we slap an "intelligent" label onto will at least demonstrate this basic desire for self-preservation. There may be exceptions to this rule, but the exceptions themselves can prove the rule, under suitable circumstances. But in general, we will recognize something as intelligent, because at some level, it will be apparent that it is *trying to guide the local universe into its preferred phase space*. And I don't see how you could have an intelligence that is *not* trying to do that. Nor do I see how you could say such an entity is *not* intelligent. This is the entirety of intelligence, and an agent is intelligent if and only if it is doing this. To the the extent that the "preferred phase space" can be described by *values*, we can then say that yes, intelligence boils down to making value judgments about current and future states, and choosing actions which maximize the value of future states.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that at its core, intelligence requires that some form of “good” or “bad” value judgments be made during the perception process.

One starting point of consideration is, are there deep differences between human intelligence and machine intelligence/artificial intelligence? Hubert Dreyfus wrote a [book](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Dreyfus%27s_views_on_artificial_intelligence) I’ve been meaning to read about this, taking a very philosophical approach that might be neglected by more mainstream AI theorists. There are a lot of theories coming from the field of phenomenology, which I have yet to study, providing a richer vocabulary of characteristics consciousness has, beyond merely “being able to process information”, answer questions accurately, reason, achieve goals, form representations of the world, etc. Philosophers like Husserl, Heidegger, and Merleau-Ponty have discussed ideas like [intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/), or, that “consciousness has to be *about* something”.

I also think you are touching on classic philosophy of mind questions, some modern thinkers who have developed such questions being David Chalmers, Thomas Nagel, and John Searle. You want to know to what extent something beyond mere rationality is necessary or intrinsic to “intelligence”, consciousness, understanding, being, etc. For example, do you think a p-zombie can logically learn all the facts about consciousness until they give indistinguishable answers about what it’s like to be conscious, or do you think it is impossible to draw identical inferences as a person endowed with consciousness without being conscious; there are forms of experience that defy logical representation but still influence how we reason; thus you could never have something like “human intelligence” without certain kinds of “subjectivity”, including qualia, sensations, preferences, etc.

I think you should study [consciousness studies](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/) heavily, to discover theories that speak to you.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that at its core, intelligence requires that some form of “good” or “bad” value judgments be made during the perception process.

Quite obviously, yes. On a raw level, people will find it good to find food everyday, they will find it good to be protected against the elements. They find it good to not be thirsty or in pain. This kind of value judgement is very clearly part of how our brains work in regards to prioritizing what to do.

Also, this kind of raw goal setting / value judgement / prioritization clearly happens in the animal world as well. A dog will easily be able to decide whether it is more important to frolick around with his friends, or whether it is more important to go hunting. Clearly, at some points in time, the value of the latter is prioritized.

So I assume you are not talking about this kind of value, but about "lofty" human values, like taking care if others, avoiding harming others, increasing the universal amount of happines, and so on and forth.

> Values are the motivation behind an objective or goal.

This seems like a very bold claim. We are seeing the opposite every day, including for ourselves. Humans, both on an individual and also on an agregate levels are having a great many objectives and goals which are motivated by anything *but* lofty values. They may be based on basic values (like having food and shelter), but often are also very clearly based on the brain being broken (i.e., a drug addict searching for their next shot).

> Values are the answer to the question, “Why?"

While is is obvious that many people seem to get hung up on the "Why?" question, it is equally obvious that not everybody requires an answer to it. There are people who have come to the belief that there is no particular reason to ask "Why?" and that there is no useful answer, anyways (at least not on an objective level). Assuming you are talking about the capital-W-why like "why are we here?", not the everyday "why do I need to find food"?

> Must intelligence continue to evolve based on values,

First you need to come up with a reason why, objectively, intelligence should have evolved based on values, in the first place. I can readily imagine scenarios where the first glimpses of intelligence had zero "big-V" values whatsoever.

In fact, the very *definition* of the word [intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence) is so all-encompassing, with many different facets, that you can attribute some aspects of intelligence to a great many of unexpected entities. Chimpanzees certainly have a modicum of intelligence. LLMs show some very specific forms of intelligence. Even abstract organisms (like ant hills) could, from a 10.000km distance, be considered *somewhat* intelligent. Heck, a company could certainly be considered intelligent in some form.

> or is it philosophically possible to have a form of intelligence that is not based on values?

Yes, of course, totally. The example of a company being an intelligent entity very clearly shows an example. Wolves intelligently stalking their prey in a group are clearly showing intelligent overall behaviour, with zero need for values of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on the terms *subjectivity*, *intelligence*, *value*. These are different and unrelated concepts. They also live on different levels.

- *Subjective* is the opposite to objective. The term can be used as an
  attribute of insights or of knowledge. It also characterizes the first-person access to our feelings and to all our perceptions.
- *Value* is often used as basic term from ethics. There it is used to
  classify objects or situations one should strive for.
- *Intelligence* is a cognitive capability. It can be used to realize arbitrary values.

I do not see how to bring these three concepts under a common heading.

Comment: Because the mods changed the title of my question *entirely*, removed 80% of the body content and moved most of the comments to chat room. They did this after a half dozen answers and several dozen comments. As a result, many of the comments and answers are disconnected and no longer make sense. I ask myself, what is the point of me posting here if I can then be misrepresented to such a degree? What is the point of me reading or answering the questions of others if they may not in fact be their questions? Due to this lack of integrity, I have scheduled my account for deletion.